# does std::move make sense on a stack variable

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to create a list of struct of size 1024. So I'm trying to optimize push operation into the list by making use of move semantics. But move semantics makes sense only for heap allocated memory(as per my knowledge). Can somebody suggest me a better way of doing this. This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
    
struct St {
    int32_t arr[1024];
};
    
int main() {
    std::list<St> struct_list;
    for(int32_t i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
        St st; // stack allocated and memory gets deallocated after each loop
        std::cout << &st << std::endl;
        struct_list.emplace_back(std::move(st)); // I feel std::move doesn't make any sense here even if I implement move constructor, still data gets copied into the std::list which is allocated in heap, so not efficient.
        std::cout << &struct_list.back() << "\n" << std::endl;
    }
        
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it shouldn't?

Comment: _"But move semantics makes sense only for heap allocated memory"_ Can you please cite, where you got this from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given your current definition of `St`:

```
struct St {
    int32_t arr[1024];
};
```

Technically, moving and copying both results is the same for this particular definition of `St`.

However, semantically it does make sense to mark `st` for moving as you are done with it, and `st` will be destroyed anyway. For example, if you later decide to change the definition of `St` to something like:

```
struct St {
    std::vector<int32_t> vec;
};
```

Then, it will make a difference – the vector data member will be moved instead of copied.

In short, my recommendation is to focus on the *semantics* of the move operation – i.e., *does it make sense for the object to be moved?* Well, if you are going to dispose of the object anyway, then it very likely does.

Answer (score 2):

If you would manage to upgrade to C++17, you could use [the return value of emplace_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/emplace_back) in order to first add it to the list and then fill it.
You could (if default constructable, as your example) first emplace_back a new instance, than use `.back()` to get it and fill it in.

Stack allocations and deallocations ain't expensive, especially for PODs. It's the logic you do onto it that's important.

Regarding the moving, for this example, the std::move will do the same as copying, so no, you don't need it. However, if this would have been an array of `std::string`, the std::move would allow you to move the strings from one array to the other.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with C++ is that `std::move` is used for two things:

1. as an optimization of copy (when the class uses resources that can be transferred, such as heap memory, a file handle, etc.).
2. put (generic) variables in an unusable (but destructible or assignable state)

The first doesn't apply because `int` doesn't have resources.
The second doesn't apply either because `int` is not a generic type.

However, in neither case should it be an error to use `std::move`.
IMO, `std::move` can be used to make the value unusable, and some static analyzers detect that, but most likely, and unfortunately, not for `int`.
(Use-after-move).

I think passing *any* variable can be marked as unusable using `std::move,` but so far, this is a pure convention and probably controversial.

For example, one could have a function `f` that scrambles an integer as it is not specified in which state it is left.
By a generalization of the generic case, this *could* be marked with an interface that allows `f(std::move(i))` in such a way that using `i` later is as bad as using it uninitialized.
However, the utility of this convention depends on the compiler warnings or other tools to share this interpretation.

As examples, I have four datapoitns, some of them contradictory about the "utility" of moving `int`. see the panels here https://godbolt.org/z/b6YoPP584

- GCC and clang do not say anything about moving int.
- clang-tidy has the check `clang-analyzer-cplusplus.Move` but it doesn't complain about moving int OR using it later.
- As a data point (counterpoint), SonarLint decided that "std::move" should not be called on an object of a built-in type " (cpp:S5415). "
  Of course, this is only if it can "see" that the variable is an `int`.
  If it is a generic type, it can't complain about using `std::move` of course.
  (This is inconsistent to me, because generic code needs to be syntactically changed when applying to a specific type.)
- PVS studio complains about using int after the move (hurray!)